# Python Unicode Issue

Tags: python, unicode

```
import re

##EDIT  didn't mean to copy filename = "rr.txt" ## opens file unicode file type
buffer = open('r.txt','r').read()

quotes = re.findall(ur'"[^"^\u201c]*["\u201d].*', buffer)
for quote in quotes:
    print ''
    print quote
## prints quotes found
## Problem is that the print output has rectangular blocks between each Character
```

Why?

How do you return output without the rectangular blocks messing everything up?

Comment: The file I used was a basic save, unicode text file, text copied from a PDF

Comment: http://parisis.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/noam-chomsky.pdf

Comment: How do you know the text file is Unicode? What OS are you running Acrobat in? In Windows it saves as a code page where the quotes are 0x93 and 0x94.

Comment: When I save the text file it gives options for encoding. They are: ANSI, unicode, unicode big endian and UFT-8. I used unicode... I'm running windows

Answer (score 4):

You're opening it incorrectly. And "Unicode" in Windows is actually UTF-16LE.

```
buffer = codecs.open('r.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-16le').read()
```

Comment: I wonder how that regular expression was finding anything if the read was messed up?

Comment: @Mark: An interesting question. I suspect that my answer isn't *completely* correct, but it is about 90% of the way there (e.g. the file is in the system encoding instead of UTF-16LE).

Comment: Thanks for the help, the Re, does need some work that i can do now. cheers

Answer (score 2):

This isn't related to Python. Your console window renders the output of Python and this breaks.

Use a font in your console window that supports the necessary Unicode characters.

Comment: The above isn't really helpful and it seems to me the problem came from using python and seems to have been fixed using python.